# Create multiple instances of html video object

Tags: html, chromecast

In my custom receiver, there is this snippet:

```
    <video id='media' width="1260" height="700" autoplay />
    <video id='videoloop' width="1260" height="700" loop autoplay />
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
          //window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('media');
          window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('videoloop');
          window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(window.mediaElement);
          window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
          window.castReceiverManager.start();
```

With this line, I can play video with sound:

```
window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('media');
```

But with this line, I can only hear sound but no video:

```
window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('videoloop');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you use videoloop, if you remove the video element corresponding to "media" element, will everything works fine?

Comment: @AliNaddaf:  If I took out the <video id='media' .... line then videoloop works fine.

Comment: You cannot have more than one active media element.

Comment: To further clarify, you can have two media element where one plays a video that doesn't have any audio and the second one plays only audio. You cannot have two active video or two active audio pipelines at the same time.