# Chromecast not playing multiple HTML5 videos

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, chromecast

I have 2 video players on single page. On desktop, everything works fine, both video players are playing videos. But when I try to cast this page to Chromecast (via Google Chrome extension or via https://demille.github.io/url-cast-receiver/), only first video player is active and playing, second video player is not working.

I tried to debug it and it looks like second video ends at video readyState=1 (first video has readyState=4)

Is there way to fix this? (I need multiple video players on single page, so using only one player and switching video files URLs is not a solution)

URL: http://iuvomedia.eu/chromecast/

Comment: are you trying to play both videos at the same time, or just let the user choose which to play/cast?

Comment: not included in example I mentioned, but only one video is playing and other video player is just loading video data and is hidden. When first video finish playing, second one is displayed and called by play() function.

But visibility does not matter because it is not playing even if both videos are visible.

It really looks like Chromecast can not load video data from second player when another video player is playing video..

I also tried to call load() function on second video, but without success - loading of videos and on status readyState=1 (loaded metadata).

Comment: have you looked at the Chromecast JS api? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate

Comment: yes, I have looked on it, but it is not a solution for me, I need 2 or more active video players in one moment and also on webpage there will be another content, for example texts and images, so I do not need only video player...

Answer (score 5):

If you want one video to play and other to be pre-loaded then you should make a queue of videos you want to play. Chromecast will play single video at a time and when it ends it'll automatically load the next one in the queue.

For information on autoplay and queuing you may visit https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/autoplay

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot have more than one active media element.**

I mean, you can have two media elements where one plays a video that doesn't have any audio and the second one plays only audio.

You cannot have two active video or two active audio pipelines at the same time.

**check here:** [Create multiple instances of html video object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977396/create-multiple-instances-of-html-video-object)

Comment: What is "active media element"? When I have one video player playing and second one paused (only preloading data), is this situation with two active elements? I need second video player just to preload video to be ready to play when first player finish playing...

Comment: that's the video you are speaking in your question